# spring boot and angular js using Rest service and post methode to send an object

Tags: java, angularjs, object, post, spring-boot

I'm new to AngularJS and spring boot I need to submit data via form  a null object pass in the post method this is HTML file:

```
<body ng-app="MyCat" ng-controller="CatController" >
<form>
<label>des:</label>
 <input  type="text" ng-model="m.des"  name="des">
 <label>prix:</label>
 <input  type="text" ng-model="m.prix" name="prix" >
 <input ng-click="submit()" type="button" value="ajouter"/>
 </br></br>
 </form>
</body>
```

**this is my app.js code**

```
 var MyCat = angular.module('MyCat',[]);
    MyCat.controller('CatController',function($scope,$http){
        $scope.produit=[];
        $scope.motCle=null;
        $scope.pageCourante=0;
        $scope.m={};
         $scope.submit = function() {
             $http.post("/save",$scope.m)
              .success(function(data) {
              alert("Task added");
                });
           };   
});
```

**this is my rest controller class**

```
@RestController
    public class CatalogueController {
    @Autowired
    private IProduitRepository prouitRepository ;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Produit SaveProduit(@RequestBody Produit p){
        return prouitRepository.save(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the issue?

Comment: a null object pass in the post method

Answer (score 0):

you can't save a null object this `prouitRepository.save(p)` Throws:
IllegalArgumentException - in case the given entity is null.